# Gmail,Yahoo, Facebook, Twitter contacts importer in PHP

Tags: php, facebook, twitter, gmail, contacts

Which is the greatest, cheapest application in PHP that I can buy to import Gmail, Yahoo, MSN, Facebook, Twitter contacts from my user's accounts if they wish to invite their friends?

I have gone through:

http://www.improsys.com/importer.htm
http://www.octazen.com/demo.php
and
http://www.iplussoft.com/product/iplusinvite_pricing

Octazen looks awesome but wants excess of $320 for an all in solution. I don't want to spend that much.

All you PHP programmers out there you may have needed to build of integrate a similar app, I need to know which is the best PHP readymade app for this?

Any help would be appreciated and I'll smile with each answer - this should be your biggest incentive to find me something amazing :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

a quick google search gave [openinviter](http://openinviter.com) which should do what you want for free (open source)

Comment: It doesn't have Twitter.. thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Actually, there is twitter.. my bad. Thank you for the answer.. truly the best answer! cheers

Comment: Open inviter does not work properly now. I have downloaded their latest code but yahoo contacts dont work. Tried gmail and hotmail and its works fine only yahoo is not working..

Comment: Yahoo and Msn dont work using Openinviter. Plz suggest some other

Comment: Openinviter is a scam! it doesn't really work for any provider, they just store you details on their sexy big database of innocent people like you who believed it really works ! I trust that i have informed you sufficiently :)

Comment: Try out the social inviter, http://socialinviter.com the updates are free and the plugin is up to date all the time. Easy to integrate and configure.

Comment: Safly, openinviter is not available anymore..

Answer (score 1):

open inviter is what you are looking for ... and guess what its free !!! and support almost every thing .... even the dead site hi5 !!

Answer (score 0):

I Like OpenInviter. this script is very good.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the octazen sript but openinviter is very nice as well and openviter has a page that shows all services that have been checked to be working for like the past hour, that is awsome

Answer (score -4):

Check out [Facebook Contact Importer](http://www.facebookcontactimporter.com). I think it might be what you are looking for. Hope this helps

Comment: Your just trying to pimp your product.