# How to get name,EmailID to invite gmail contacts in GmailOath

Tags: php, gmail, xampp, google-oauth

I am building one website where i want to invite user gmail contact.

using GmailOath [using this](http://www.9lessons.info/2011/06/import-gmail-contacts-google-oauth.html) i can able to get email ids and phone number of gmail user contacts but i am not able to get names for those emailIDs.

Can any one help me on this.how to get name

My code is:

contact.php

```
<?php
include_once 'GmailOath.php';
include_once 'Config.php';
session_start();
$oauth =new GmailOath($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $argarray, $debug, $callback);
$getcontact_access=new GmailGetContacts();

$request_token=$oauth->rfc3986_decode($_GET['oauth_token']);
$request_token_secret=$oauth->rfc3986_decode($_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']);
$oauth_verifier= $oauth->rfc3986_decode($_GET['oauth_verifier']);

$contact_access = $getcontact_access->get_access_token($oauth,$request_token, $request_token_secret,$oauth_verifier, false, true, true);

$access_token=$oauth->rfc3986_decode($contact_access['oauth_token']);
$access_token_secret=$oauth->rfc3986_decode($contact_access['oauth_token_secret']);
$contacts= $getcontact_access->GetContacts($oauth, $access_token, $access_token_secret, false, true,$emails_count);

foreach($contacts as $k => $a)
{
    $final = end($contacts[$k]);


    foreach($final as $email)
    {
        echo. $email["address"] ."<br />";
    }
}


?>
```

i want to `name` with there `emailid`.

NOTE: i tried to used http://openinviter.com/ which is mention [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145691/gmail-yahoo-facebook-twitter-contacts-importer-in-php) but i not got.